# Are Superluminous supernova and Hypernova the same thing?

Tags: star, supernova, stellar-evolution

Are Superluminous supernova and Hypernova the same thing? Is there any difference with their formation, luminosity etc?

Answer (score 2):

Superluminous supernovae are supernovae that are substantially brighter than a typical supernova. There may be a number of reasons that supernova might be Bright: A pair-instability supernova can be especially bright, or if the star is embedded in a nebula of material, the interaction between the shockwave and this material can convert kinetic energy to heat and light, causing the supernova to appear much brighter than normal.

Another way for a superluminous supernova to form is the collapse of the core into a rapidly rotating black hole. The material falling onto the rotating black hole produces jets of material moving at relativistic speeds, and these can transfer energy from the infalling matter to the shell of matter ejected by the supernova. This type of superluminous supernova is called a *hypernova*, and it can be 10 or 100 times brighter than a typical supernova.

So in the strict sense, hypernovae are a particular type of superluminous supernova. You can probably find some use of hypernova in the more general sense, in which case it is just a synonym of superluminous supernova.

(principally sourced from Wikipedia [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superluminous_supernova}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superluminous_supernova%7D)

Answer (score -5):

Attractive force of approximately 2.31 x 10^-8 Newtons between an electron and a proton in an atom.

The force of attraction experienced by an electron at the surface of Sirius B due to its gravity is approximately 1.45 x 10^-12 Newtons.

Once it reached the 2.31 x 10^-8, electrons start to be ripped off atoms in direction to its core, making nucleons jump of in opposite direction forming gamma radiation preceding to the Supernova.

Since ratio of the volume of the hydrogen atom to the volume of its nucleus is approximately 2.67 x 10^15, the volume of the star collapses.

Electrons being ripped off with speed comparable to the speed of light, so almost instantaneously the star density decreased approximately 2.67 x 10^15 times makes the collapse.

In result the supernova forms the core object consisting of the super-dense plasma of nucleons and electrons.

This core may either loose density and nucleolus start to rip electrons back to form hydrogen atoms again which makes the core rebirth to a star of Sun type. Or it happens to take enough mass to keep the density and grow in bigger star. Which potentially may lead to hypernova is next level similar process which affect quarks consistency to form a black whole singularity.

Comment: This answer reads like something generated by ChatGPT. It doesn't even attempt to address the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But @GregBurghardt, did you read to the end, it covers the question on Hypernova

Comment: Can you confirm that the answer you "wrote" is your own writing or is it chatgpt generated? If it is your own writing, you should probably provide some reference.

Comment: The last part talks about hypernova, but I'm not clear how it relates to the question.

Comment: @NilayGhosh, it is my, but I used the ChatGPT for calculations of facts about gravity values. So my answer contains some copypaste of that.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, the question has two parta. Is it the same and about the difference between if it is not the same. The part of the hypernova states that it is different process and states the difference about its gravity gauges.